# how to save files in a text file using tkinter in a dictionary form and reading or displaying them in a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

i have been able to write a function that can save entries or info about a person from entry widgets into a text file..and i have also written a function that can search the info of a person by typing the name of a person in another entry widget which displays the info of that person in a text widget,,but i get an error when i try to display another info in the text widget..these are the codes

```
    def adduser():
        name = "Name: " + entry_box1.get()
        course = "Course: " + entry_box2.get()
        reference_number = "Ref Number : " + entry_box3.get()

        email = "Email : " + entry_box6.get()
        timestamp = str(now)

        data[name] = course, reference_number, email, timestamp
        addstudent = open ("data.txt", "a")

        addstudent.write(str(data))
        addstudent.close()
```

and this is the read function

```
    def read():
        query = open ("data.txt", "r").read()

        data = eval(query)


        name = "Name: " + s_b.get()
        if name in data:
            tt.insert(0.,data[name])
```

Comment: What is the error  you get?

Comment: 'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Don Gewa\Downloads\data_storage.py\data_storage.py", line 169, in read
    data = eval(query)
  File "<string>", line 1
    {'Name: lol': ('Course: lol', 'Ref Number : lol', 'Email : lol', '2014-08-25 00:19:10.037075')}{'Name: hmm': ('Course: hmm', 'Ref Number : mm', 'Email : hmm', '2014-08-25 00:19:44.691004')}
                                                                     SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: when i change the write code from "a" to "w" it works perfectly if the program is running but when i close the program and run it again.it doesnt work.

Comment: It looks like the data you write isn't eval'able. You're getting a syntax error when trying to eval it. Using eval in this way is very dangerous. You should consider using something like the json module to read and write json data.

Comment: thanks...when i remove the eval from the code...it doesnt run..i get TypeError: string indices must be integers